# Celery worker and worker process

Tags: celery, django-celery

What is the relation between a worker and a worker process in celery? Does it make sense to run multiple workers on a single machine?
Here is the system configuration

8 core and 32GB RAM.

The celery configuration I tried was as below

```
celery -A Comments_DB worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=8
```

I want to increase the number of requests processed in a given time frame. Which is a better approach?

a. 2 Workers with concurrency set to 8 each( 2*8 = 16) or

b. 1 Worker with concurrency set to 16 *1*16=16) ?

Could anyone please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

A worker (parent process) will have one or more worker processes (child processes).  That way if any of the children die because of an error or because of a max task limit, the parent can kick off another child process.

One parent process with concurrency of 16 will generally have better performance than two processes with concurrency of 8.  This is because there is less process overhead with one process than with two.  You might want two processes if you had multiple queues and wanted to make sure that a slower queue wasn't blocking other important queue tasks from processing.

Comment: I suspect change in performance is dependent on many factors. The best way to find out is to benchmark. In my setup having more workers improves throughput with minimal affect on other areas.